# How to manually add symbols with plotly in R

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have a plot_ly 3D scatter plot that uses three traces, and I want to use a different symbol and color for each trace. My code looks like this

```
library(plotrix)
library(plotly)
library(processx)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
z1 <- z + 1.5
df1 <- data.frame(x, y, z1)
z2 <- z + 3
df2 <- data.frame(x, y, z2)
symbols <- c("circle", "diamond", 'triangle-down')
colors <- c("gray", "lightgray", "darkslategray")
plot<- plot_ly()%>%
  add_trace(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,type = "scatter3d",
    mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 8, symbol = 1, symbols = symbols, color = 1, colors = colors)) %>%
  add_trace(data = df1, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z1,type = "scatter3d",
            mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 8, symbol = 2, symbols = symbols, color = 2, colors = colors)) %>%
  add_trace(data = df2, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z2,type = "scatter3d",
            mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 8, symbol = 8, symbols = symbols, color = 3, colors = colors)) %>%
  layout(title = 'Explore Options')
plot
```

which I would like to have the first trace to use circle markers, the second diamond and the third triangles, each with a different gray scale color, but instead I just get colored circles i.e.
[image: three traceas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a column to your dataframes which could then be mapped on the `color` and `symbol` attributes. Additionally I use named vectors of `colors` and `symbols` to assign colors and symbols to categories of the new column. Also note that `colors` and `symbols` should not to be placed inside the `list` for the marker specifications. Finally I simplified your code a bit.

The `"triangle-down"` symbol does not work, according to this [reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter3d/#scatter3d-marker-symbol), only  ( "circle" | "circle-open" | "cross" | "diamond" | "diamond-open" | "square" | "square-open" | "x" ) are accepted.

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
z1 <- z + 1.5
df1 <- data.frame(x, y, z = z1)
z2 <- z + 3
df2 <- data.frame(x, y, z = z2)

df$color <- "a"
df1$color <- "b"
df2$color <- "c"
symbols <- c("circle", "diamond", 'square')
colors <- c("gray", "lightgray", "darkslategray")
names(colors) <- names(symbols)  <- c("a", "b", "c")

plot<- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, color = ~color, symbol = ~color, colors = colors, symbols = symbols, marker = list(size = 8)) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_trace(data = df1, type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_trace(data = df2, type = "scatter3d", mode = 'markers') %>%
  layout(title = 'Explore Options')
plot
```

[image]

Comment: Yep. Looks you are right. According to https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter3d/#scatter3d-marker-symbol scatter 3D allows only for a limited number of symbols.